# Black Screen During Ubuntu Installation

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot

I was dual-booting Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS with my main OS, Windows 8.1 and in the middle of the installation, the screen turned to black. The laptop was still on, but the screen was black.
Is this supposed to happen? Will my PC bootloader get corrupt? The computer is an Acer Aspire E5-521-238Q.

What do I do to stop the black screen?

Answer (score 0):

It would be difficult to say precisely as to what must have happened, but I can give you a few suggestions:

- Wait for some more time. It might be possible that some installation process is running in the background.
- There might be an issue with the GRUB. In such a case you will have to do a fresh install. There might be a possibility that your windows has been irreparably damaged, and you may have to do a fresh install of windows.

The best thing that I would suggest for you is to use a virtual machine like VMWare from within windows. This gives you the added benefit of using Linux (on a virtual machine) alongside windows as your primary OS.

Comment: I use virtual machines but I wanted more RAM so I tried a dual-boot. Does that mean I have to wipe ALL my data if it happens? Because I don't actually have any disc of Windows, I need to use diskpart and that definitely will wipe all my data so now I am even more worried. But thanks for giving me the possibilities. Also, how long exactly will it take for an Ubuntu install?

Comment: If you use VMWare, then you do have an option of allocating required RAM to the OS installed within the VM. For eg., in my case, the default RAM allocated for Ubuntu (installed within the VM) was 1 GB, which I later changed to 4. As for the time taken for the installation of Ubuntu, it would be roughly around 15-20 minutes (I'm talking about version 14.04 in particular). This time may vary depending upon the version you choose.